# LD1117v33 to get 3.3v

Tags: voltage-regulator

I am using ld1117v33 with Vin as 4.97v and trying to get Vout as 3.3v. I am actually getting this Vout without using any capacitors or resistors. The datasheet has suggested to use two capacitors, 0.1uf for input and 10uf for output along with a 120 ohm load resistor.

[image]

When I follow the circuit, I am getting Vout as 3.27v.

I can understand the usage of capacitors but not sure about the resistor used here. Could someone tell that if there is any advantage of using the resistor here? When I remove the resistor and leave the capacitors, it does go back to 3.3V.

Comment: P.S: When I remove the resistor, I am getting the expected Vout 3.3v

Comment: There's no resistor in your schematic.

Comment: @adam the datasheet shows one for the 1.2V version.

Comment: @Passerby I know. :-) I was suggesting that Senthil update the question to show what he's talking about instead of assuming that we'll Google the datasheet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 120 ohm resistor is only required for the 1.2V version of the LD1117 to maintain minimum regulation, with a 10 mA minimum load. It's unneeded for the 3.3V version.

[image]

That said, 3.27V is within the specs for the 3.3V version. See the V<sub>O</sub> spec on the datasheet, for the 3.3V version. The datasheet has a spec section for multiple output voltages.

[image]

***That said***, a 120 ohm resistor is only a 27 mA load at 3.3V. Try a larger load like 250mA and check to see if the voltage is still within range. Make sure your capacitors are as close to the LDO as possible. You may need a larger input capacitor depending on how far away your power supply is. If it's not within range at a higher load up to 800 mA it may be bad. **And this is for the ST branded LD1117, other brands may have different requirements or specs.**